# Power BI Report Server - Shared Dataset Doesn't Save

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi-datasource

[Data Source missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2W2d.png)
[Data Source,tried to save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOWSR.png)
The issue is when I hit save to connect to a shared data source it doesn't save. When I run the report and get the below error. Then go back and the shared data source is gone. I can see that the link and extensions are null. Please help :-)

The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset. The shared data source 'SSAS_PRN' for the report server is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem = There was many different versions of the same data sets.

The solution was to wipe out all of them, then start fresh.
Then in Report builder.
Under the data Sources Properties.
Browse to the new version.
Hit save.
The report now works on the server.